# Avoid man in the middle (proxy) Android

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, reverse-engineering, man-in-the-middle

I got a task at my job to reverse engineer an application.

I've been using [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) several times with other applications without any problems and have also tried [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/). I've always been able to monitor the request/responses made.

But the application that I'm trying now does now show any activity in either [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/). First I thought that they check the certificate and kill the connection but the application works as normal without any hiccups.

Is there any way for an application to be able to avoid the proxy settings or what am I missing?

I've been using [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) as well as [dex2jar](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) and found this peace of code. Probably not 100% correct but it can give you some clues of what happening.

```
public final void a(int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
  {
    this.b = paramInt2;
    InetSocketAddress localInetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(this.a), this.b);
    while (true)
    {
      try
      {
        SSLContext localSSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        X509TrustManager[] arrayOfX509TrustManager = new X509TrustManager[1];
        arrayOfX509TrustManager[0] = new c(this);
        localSSLContext.init(null, arrayOfX509TrustManager, new SecureRandom());
        this.e = ((SSLSocket)localSSLContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket());
        this.e.connect(localInetSocketAddress, paramInt1);
        this.d.clear();
        if (Arrays.asList(this.e.getSupportedProtocols()).contains("TLSv1.2"))
        {
          this.d.add("TLSv1.2");
          String[] arrayOfString1 = (String[])this.d.toArray(new String[this.d.size()]);
          SSLSocket localSSLSocket1 = this.e;
          if (arrayOfString1.length > 0)
            localSSLSocket1.setEnabledProtocols(arrayOfString1);
          this.c.clear();
          if (!Arrays.asList(this.e.getSupportedCipherSuites()).contains("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"))
            break label374;
          this.c.add("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA");
          String[] arrayOfString2 = (String[])this.c.toArray(new String[this.c.size()]);
          SSLSocket localSSLSocket2 = this.e;
          if (arrayOfString2.length > 0)
            localSSLSocket2.setEnabledCipherSuites(arrayOfString2);
          e.a().a(this.e.getLocalAddress().getAddress());
          e.a().a(this.e.getLocalPort());
          a(5000);
          this.e.startHandshake();
          a(0);
          return;
        }
      }
      catch (Exception localException)
      {
        throw new IOException(localException.toString());
      }
      if (Arrays.asList(this.e.getSupportedProtocols()).contains("TLSv1.1"))
      {
        this.d.add("TLSv1.1");
      }
      else if (Arrays.asList(this.e.getSupportedProtocols()).contains("TLSv1"))
      {
        this.d.add("TLSv1");
        continue;
        label374: if (Arrays.asList(this.e.getSupportedCipherSuites()).contains("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"))
          this.c.add("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA");
        else if (Arrays.asList(this.e.getSupportedCipherSuites()).contains("SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"))
          this.c.add("SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA");
        else if (Arrays.asList(this.e.getSupportedCipherSuites()).contains("DES-CBC3-SHA"))
          this.c.add("DES-CBC3-SHA");
      }
    }
  }
```

Don't know that much about TLS 1.2 but I know its suppose to be more robust? But can it avoid the proxy?

I've also dumped the traffic using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), that worked but the information is encrypted, as expected, so its not much of use.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried sniffing all traffic coming from your device? That being said, if you're serious about intercepting traffic from an Android app, it would be best for you to build your own Android distribution that includes hooks to capture what you want, and run the application under that custom build (either on a real device or, much easier, in an emulator).

Comment: hm... yeah, guess I could to a custom build, a more complex solution than what I was hoping for but if nothing else works... But still any idea why I cant see the traffic in Charles Proxy or Fiddler?

Answer (score 2):

This code will probably avoid proxy because is making direct socket. If you are using some higher level api, like HttpURLConnection, it respect proxy settings.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

You can try using SandroProxy to find out on which port communication is made.

http://code.google.com/p/sandrop/issues/detail?id=76

1. Go to HTTP tab and pres play button on acction bar
   SandroProxy will listen on two new ports 8020 -> web , 8021 -> websockets for chrome devtools
2. start chrome from PC with url http your_device_ip:8020
3. Check Connection tab, last two columns are process uid and names(can be more than one)

To capture data you can also use SandroProxy and force iptable redirects. You will need rooted phone.

btw: send by sandroproxy support :)

Comment: Hi, thanks, your right, it is a direct proxy so thats why I haven't been able to monitor the traffic, I got it to work with some other tools already but I can only monitor the encrypted traffic, is there any way I can configure sandroproxy for man in the middle?

Comment: Yes. Enable capture data, transparent proxy in settings. Also activate iptable rules in App tab. To intercept ssl you should also import SandroProxy ca certificate to android os cert store with Menu->Export CA . Then you can monitor traffic in Http tab or in chrome in Network panel

Comment: sry for late response, other tasks have been prioritized before this. Anyways. Do you have any tips on how I should set up the iptables? The application uses outgoing port 4710 and incoming (random port) to an address, lets say 111.111.111.111. How can I set up iptables so that it connects through SandroProxy? the APPS tap does not seemt to work, guess its because the connection uses port 4710? If this works I will give you a quite a few beers in donation :)

Comment: iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -m owner ! --uid-owner 10062 -p tcp --dport 4710 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:8010   ->where uid-owner(10062) is process uid for sandroproxy. it must be excluded so it can make connection to real 4710. Maybe you will also need settings-CA certificate->[Trust all SSL certificate] if server has some untrusted ca. Probably some new version of sandroproxy will have also custom port redirection, not just 443 and 80. what kind of beer are we talking about? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like `adb forward 80 3456` against the device or emulator to have all port 80 traffic redirected to 3456 on your workstation.  Then have your proxy listen on that port.